# Php problem with The IF statment

Tags: php, html, file, if-statement

**Hey guys, now i need to check the contents of two files to make sure there the same**

```
<?php
$tk1 = file_get_contents("done.txt");
$tk2 = file_get_contents("guessed.txt");
echo $tk1."<br>";
echo $tk2;
echo "<br>";
if($tk2 == (string)$tk1){
echo "got it";
}else{
echo "aww";
}
?>
```

Okay inside done.txt is whatonearth and inside guessed.txt theres also whatonearth in it
But it keeps echoing aww, and never echos got it...:s. can somone help?
thanks

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code to fix. The two files don't have the same content. If they *look* the same, one has extra spaces or blank lines or something like that.

Comment: What's with the string casting? I don't think that needs to be done. Try removing the cast.

Comment: Yes i thought about that, I even used preg_replace to remove any spaces, But there arn't. Im soo confused....

Comment: It can be a character you can't see, like a byte-order-mark.

Comment: i removed it, Still giving my the same thing.

Comment: Maybe you should re-specify your requirements, then. How many characters do you want to remove and still consider the file contents equivalent?

Comment: Is it possible to supply links to the two files? Try doing strlen on the two strings.

Comment: The fill contents of, whatonearth cannot change, i just want both the files to equal the same thing, witch for some reason there not, i got no idea why that is though...is there a way to remove any bytes that are hidden?

Comment: No sorry. i don't have the files up anywhere.

Comment: cat -v/od is useful to see if there is any unseen sharacters

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though `done.txt` and `guessed.txt` don't have the same contents. Maybe one has extra whitespace at the end, or something similarly inconspicuous. Instead of doing `echo $tk1;` and `echo $tk2;` I would recommend that you use `var_dump` so that you can see exactly what values those variables have.

Comment: I used var dump heres the results: string(12) "whatonearth " string(11) "whatonearth"

Comment: Thank you thank you, i used: $sPattern = '/\s*/m'; 
$sReplace = '';
 
$donerr = preg_replace( $sPattern, $sReplace, $donerr ); and it removed the 1 char at the end, thanks guys, i think it works now

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted works, so my assumption would be that there is a subtle difference between the two files.

How are these files created? Are they uploaded by a user? Generated by PHP? If one or both of them are coming from an outside source, then you should check how newlines are handled. If one file uses CR+LF for newlines (i.e. "Windows-style"), but another is just LF (i.e. "Unix-Style"), then the comparison would fail.

Comment: They are created by another script. just using fopen and fwrite.

Comment: @teaguen - In that case, could you show us the code that generates them?

Comment: its 180 lines long, am i aloud to post code that long? sorry im new.

Answer (score 0):

> if($tk2 == (string)$tk1){

Don't know much about php but wont the casting change $tk1?

Comment: file_get_contents returns a string. The cast is meaningless here.

Comment: i know, sorry i was just thinking maybe there diffrent file types, because ive tried almost everything i can think of and it still wont work